# Sum about sine function

Tags: calculus

Is it possible to calculate the following in closed form?
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{2 x}{k}-\frac{\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  n x}{k}\right)}{\pi  n}\right)$$ It does not seem convergent for any value of x or n.
It is an interesting question about the Dirichlet problem.

Answer (score 1):

Note that as the function $\displaystyle \frac{u-\sin(u)}{u^3}$ has a finite limit as $u\to 0$, and goes to $0$ if $|u|\to +\infty$, there exists $M$ such that for all $|u|$, we have $|u-\sin(u)|\leq M|u|^3$. Now consider the series 
 $$G(y)=\sum_{k\geq 1}(\frac{y}{k}-\sin(\frac{y}{k}))$$

Fix $y\in \mathbb{R}$.  By the above, for all $k\geq 1$, we have $\displaystyle |\frac{y}{k}-\sin(\frac{y}{k})\leq \frac{M|y|^3}{k^3}$, hence the series $F$ is (pointwise) convergent on $\mathbb{R}$. As your series is $\frac{G(2\pi nx)}{n\pi}$, your series is pointwise convergent for all $x$ and $n$.

But of course, this does not give a closed formula for the sum.

Comment: At Least it clarifies something thanks